# laptop settings after switching to large monitor

Tags: windows-10, external-display, asus-laptop, display-settings, zenbook

I use an ASUS (ASUSTek) ZenBook laptop running 64-bit Windows 10 Home. Usually, I have it connected to a monitor, with the Windows projection setting "second screen only", so I do my work on the monitor. However, sometimes, I need to take the laptop with me somewhere, and so I disconnect it. Sometimes, when I return to my desk and plug the monitor in again, I find that scrollbars are wide, tooltips use a large font, and some other things look funny — all as if I'm still on a laptop.

1. When this happens, how can I update the display to that it recognizes I'm once again on a full-size monitor?
2. How can I prevent its happening?